# SSRS Can I sum a column with the column-value of all rows but one?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Having a grouped tablix.

I can easily add a sum row:

- Right Click in row group
- Add Total / After
- Then write a custom expression: `=Sum(Fields!myColumn.Value)`

This will sum the column 'myColumn' in all rows, but I need to sum all rows except the first one.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have a any special value for that row

Comment: =Sum(Fields!myColumn.Value) - FIRST(Fields!myColumn.Value). I think that should work